# ffmpeg concatenation produces an over-long result with no sound and partially wrong speed

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg 4.2.4.

I have two short bits of video, both shot on my phone. I cut a section out of the first one (starting 18 seconds in, and also 18 seconds long - the output seems to be 18.02 seconds long):

```
ffmpeg -i VID_20201205_135951.mp4 -ss 00:18 -t 00:18 1.mp4
```

And am using the whole of the second one, which is 13.55 seconds long:

```
cp VID_20201205_140804.mp4 2.mp4
```

I wrote a file concat.txt:

```
file '1.mp4'
file '2.mp4'
```

And used the concat filter to join them together:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i concat.txt -c copy 12.mp4
```

The resulting video has no sound, and is 3 minutes, 2.35 seconds long! If i watch it, the first 18 seconds is right (although with no sound), then it freezes, showing the last frame of the first part, until 1:47, at which point the second part starts playing, but very slowly, until the end of the video.

Any idea what i am doing wrong? Or how i could debug this?

Here's the information ffmpeg prints for the first input:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:18.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17735 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 17678 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
```

The second input:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2020-12-05T14:08:20.000000Z
    com.android.version: 11
  Duration: 00:00:13.55, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 40373 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, smpte170m), 3840x2160, 42298 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30.02 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 180
      creation_time   : 2020-12-05T14:08:20.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -180.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-12-05T14:08:20.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
```

And the output:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '12.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:03:02.35, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4734 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4719 kb/s, 5.07 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 80 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All inputs must have the same attributes. Yours have different H.264 profiles (Baseline vs High) and frame rates.

Make one video match the other:

```
ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -c:v libx264 -r 30 -c:a copy 2b.mp4
```

High profile will be picked by default, so you don't need to manually add it, but if you wanted Baseline instead use `-profile:v baseline`.

Or convert all videos to a comment set of attributes regardless of input attributes. See [How to concatenate videos in ffmpeg with different attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367243/)

Comment: Aha! If i look at the video file from which i cut the first clip i get `Video: h264 (Baseline)` and `29.98 fps`. So when i cut it out, it somehow became high profile? And also, the raw videos have slightly odd frame rates (29.98 for the first, 30.02 for the second)? Anyway, this works, thanks!

Comment: @TomAnderson Not all settings are copied from input to output. The encoder itself may have some default settings regardless of input attributes. In this case libx264 chooses High profile unless you tell it otherwise. High is best but some really old devices can't handle it and must use Main or Baseline. Some devices record to Main or Baseline because it's simpler. The video with the weird frame rate (30.02) is likely Variable Frame Rate, so upon re-encoding ffmpeg has to choose a constant frame rate and uses the lowest framerate with which all timestamps can be represented accurately.